# How to make test POST request in php artisan?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to make POST request, can I do it via PHP artisan?

I tried this using `GuzzleHttp`, but I get error:

```
ServerException in RequestException.php line 107:
Server error: `POST http://localhost/public/api/order` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
<style>
(truncated...)
```

So, is it possible with artisan?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not sure how efficient my method is, but this is an example I have run in the past.

- Go into project directory.
- Type `php artisan tinker`
- Create an array of paramaters to pass:

`$params = ['paramOne' => 'valueOne', 'paramTwo' => 'valueTwo'];`

- Create a new instance of the request you want to send. The default request type will be:

`$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::create($uri, $method, $params);`

- If you created your own request class from the Illuminate one, A custom request could be something like this:

`$request = App\Http\Requests\MyExtendedRequest::create($uri, $methodType, $params);`

`$uri` is where you want to send the request
`$methodType` is the type of HTTP Method to use (GET, POST, PUT, etc)

- Create controller that handles the request

`$controller = new App\Http\Controllers\MyController;`

- Submit the request.

`$response = $controller->storeMission($request);`

Comment: if using a formRequst to validate this will give an error of validated() on null. To make it work alter $request = yourclass::create($uri, $method, $params); and then skip the rest and use $request->post();  or whichever verb you need.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using tinker, why not run a local server and make a request to it?

`php artisan tinker serve`

Comment: because some of us like to stay in the command line. A curl command might be useful.